# Selenium not clicking on LIKE button on Instagram

Tags: selenium, click, selenium-chromedriver

For some reason, the Instagram bot seems to work but selenium is not clicking on the Like button. What may be the issue? Thank you.

```
    unique_photos = len(pic_hrefs)
    for pic_href in pic_hrefs:
        driver.get(pic_href)
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
            like_button = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@aria-label="Like"]').click()
            like_button().click()
            print('Liked!')
            for second in reversed(range(0, random.randint(18, 28))):
                print_same_line("#" + hashtag + ': unique photos left: ' + str(unique_photos)
                                + " | Sleeping " + str(second))
                time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(2)
        unique_photos -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 //article[1]//div[2]//section[1]//span[1]//button[1]//*[local-name()='svg']
```

and if you want to click on all like button then you need to use below xpath undoubtedly you need list to handle it ::

```
//article[*]//div[2]//section[1]//span[1]//button[1]//*[local-name()='svg']
```